# How to update selected rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an update query like below.

```
update logs join user
set logs.userid=user.userid
where logs.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%") and user.userID != "";
```

What I want to do is join logs table records which has not null logs.logId data.

```
logs.logId is not null
```

When I use "on" condition I think mysql first joins both table with all data then it checks logs.logId is null or not. What I really want to do is **first** eliminate log records which has null logId **then** join with user table and execute remaining statements.

```
update logs join user
on logs.logId is not null
set logs.userid=user.userid
where logs.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%") and user.userID != "";
```

**EDIT:** I need a query like below but mysql doesn't permit this query.

```
update (select * from logs where logs.logId is not null) as log join user
set log.userid=user.userid
where log.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%") and user.userID != "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `WHERE` condition to `JOIN ON` condition but either way it should achieve the same I believe.

```
update logs join user
on logs.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%") 
and logs.logId is not null
set logs.userid = user.userid
where user.userID != "";
```

Comment: I think it still tries to join both table first then tries to eliminates wrt. join on condition. Think that I have 100billion records in logs table and there are only 5 records which has not null logs.logId.

Comment: @hellzone, Join will occur only based on ON condition(s) have been applied. Give it a try and see the generated plan. That will get you better idea about cost of the query.

Comment: It still takes nearly same amount of time with my example query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the condition in the `where` clause:

```
update logs l join
       user u
       on l.log_detail LIKE concat('%', u.userID, '%')
set l.userid = u.userid
where l.userid is null and user.userID <> '';
```

This checks that `logs.userid` *is* NULL before doing the update, which seems like the most likely logic.

Comment: I think it still tries to join both table first then tries to eliminates wrt. join on condition. This query still takes nearly hours to complete. What I want to do is "first select logs which has not null logId and then join this rows(there are only 5 rows which has not null logId and 100billion rows with null logId) with user table and after that check for userid and log_detail and update logs records."

Comment: @hellzone . . . Change the condition to the correct condition and add an index on that column.  The index should fix the performance problem.

Comment: When I remove "on l.log_detail LIKE concat('%', u.userID, '%')" line it executes only 1 second faster with my dump data. (15 sec to 14 sec)

Answer (score 0):

using CTE should help 
some code like below might work:

```
;with CTE as
(
select logs.* from logs where logs.logId is not null
)
update CTE join user
set CTE.userid=user.userid
where logs.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%") and user.userID != "";
```

Comment: Mysql doesn't support CTE I think.

Comment: I didn't know that.. As tag says SQL i tried the solution this way. It will work in MSSQL.

Comment: @hellzone, NO; MySQL does support CTE as well as recursive CTE.

Comment: Did anyone check if this query is working as expected(in MySql)??